# Setting up React Native Skia - ValidationError: Invalid configuration object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack

I'm trying to get React Native Skia working in my project.  Below is the webpack.config

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { sources } = require('webpack');
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require("@expo/webpack-config");


module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
  const enviroment = {
    ...env,
    pwa: true,
    babel: {
      dangerouslyAddModulePathsToTranspile: ["@draftbit", "@amplitude"],
    },
  };

  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(enviroment, argv);

  config.resolve.alias['victory-native'] = 'victory';

  config.resolve.fallback = { 
    "fs": false, 
    "net": false, 
    "tls": false,
    // Add other node modules you want to polyfill 
  };

  
  config.plugins.forEach(({ config }) => {
    if (config && "skipWaiting" in config) {
      config.skipWaiting = false;
      config.clientsClaim = false;
    }
  });

  // Merge with new configuration
  const newConfiguration = {
    ...config,
    plugins: [
      ...config.plugins,
      // 1. Make the wasm file available to the build system
      new (class CopySkiaPlugin {
        apply(compiler) {
          compiler.hooks.thisCompilation.tap("AddSkiaPlugin", (compilation) => {
            compilation.hooks.processAssets.tapPromise(
              {
                name: "copy-skia",
                stage:
                  compiler.webpack.Compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_ADDITIONAL,
              },
              async () => {
                const src = require.resolve(
                  "canvaskit-wasm/bin/full/canvaskit.wasm"
                );
                if (compilation.getAsset(src)) {
                  // Skip emitting the asset again because it's immutable
                  return;
                }
                compilation.emitAsset(
                  "/canvaskit.wasm",
                  new sources.RawSource(await fs.promises.readFile(src))
                );
              }
            );
          });
        }
      })(),
      // 2. Polyfill fs and path module from node
      new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ],
    externals: {
      ...config.externals,
      // 3. Avoid warning if reanimated is not present
      "react-native-reanimated": "require('react-native-reanimated')",
      "react-native-reanimated/package.json":
        "require('react-native-reanimated/package.json')",
    },
  }

  return newConfiguration;
};
```

This is the error I get when I try to run via Expo:

ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

Any direction as to how to resolve would be helpful?